# Incorrect Export of CSV using tab seperator charactor

Tags: php, csv, laravel, laravel-4

This question is asked before I think, but they don't help me.
So, I have no choice.

I am using laravel to export a data in .CSV file.

What I have done is like this-

```
$tweets = DB::select(DB::raw($query));
    foreach ($tweets as $row)
    {
        $row = get_object_vars($row);
        // iterate over each tweet and add it to the csv
        $output .="col 11";     //Col 1 item
        $output .="\t";         //Adding New tab
        $output .="col 12";     //Col 2 item
        $output .="\n";     //Adding New Line
    }

    $headers = array(
        'Content-Type' => 'text/csv',
        'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment;filename="'.Carbon\Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString().'.csv"',
    );
    return Response::make(rtrim($output, "\n"), 200, $headers);
```

So, for adding a tab manually what I have done is

> $output .="\t";

And I am getting something like this-

[image]

But I want to have something like this-

[image]

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Have you opened the CSV in Sublime Text or some normal editor? Could be that your file is correct and only excel is configured wrong.

Comment: You should separate fields with `,` instead of `\t`! Please keep in mind that `CSV` stands for : `Comma Separated Values`

Comment: BTW This is not directly related to Laravel. Could you pls correct the tags?

Answer (score 1):

Proper CSV requires , separators and any fields with , " or spaces need to be wrapped with double quotes, also any double quotes appearing in the fields need to be doubled, two consecutive double quotes are treated as an escaped double quote.

Using non standard delimiters can be done but requires configuration on the client side app, standard CSV format does not. Excel has Text to Data which lets you configure separators, quoting characters and more. Numbers has a hard time with it, or at least I've had a hard time with Numbers trying to get it to open non-standard CSV properly.

The csv() function included in the controller class only for testing. Move it out or in line it. The code will wrap anything it needs to and will handle embedded \n in fields. On excel/numbers they become multi-line text cells.

```
public static
function csv($row)
{
    $csvRow = '';
    foreach ($row as $col)
    {
        $val = str_replace('"', '""', $col);
        if (preg_match('/"|,|\s|\n/', $val))
        {
            $val = "\"$val\"";
        }
        $csvRow .= ',' . $val;
    }
    return substr($csvRow, 1) . "\n";
}

public
function getTest()
{
    if (!appDebug()) return App::Abort(404);

    $tweets = DB::select('SELECT transLine, transID, transLang, transValue FROM utils.translations LIMIT 20');

    $output = '';
    foreach ($tweets as $tweet)
    {
        // output header row, optional
        // if (!$output) $output = self::csv(array_keys(get_object_vars($tweets[0])));
        $row = get_object_vars($tweet);
        $output .= self::csv($row);
    }

    $headers = array(
        'Content-Type' => 'text/csv',
        'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment;filename="' . Carbon\Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString() . '.csv"',
    );
    return Response::make(rtrim($output, "\n"), 200, $headers);
}
```